# How to properly handle CF objects created at the beginning of the program and deleted at the end

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I put

I declared 
`@property (nonatomic) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;` as the property of the class extension

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];

    CFRelease(self.addressBook);
}
```

Then in a function ONLY called by viewDidLoad, I add:
-(void) vCreateAddressBookAndPopulateContact

```
{
    self.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); //will be released at dealloc
    [self vPopulateContact];
}
```

It gives me warning:
at allocation:

```
Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

At deallocation:

```
Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
```

So, what should I do? How to tell that compiler that the object will be dereferenced latter at dealloc?

I wish I can move that ABAddressBookRef to ARC/NS land. But there is no way to do so.

self.addressBook cannot be released at the function. That's because if I want to add or remove

Comment: How is your `addressBook` property declared?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This is more a workaround, perhaps someone else has a better answer.)*

The problem does not occur if you define `addressBook` not at as property but as an instance variable (perhaps in a class extension):

```
@interface YourClass () {
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
}
```

The problem with a property is that

```
self.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
// ...
CFRelease(self.addressBook);
```

is translated to

```
[self setAddressBook:ABAddressBookCreate()];
// ...
CFRelease([self addressBook]);
```

so the static analyzer does not "see" at this point that the address book reference is preserved 
in some instance variable.

*Remark:* In `dealloc`, you should check that `addressBook` is not `NULL`

```
if (addressBook != NULL)
    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

to avoid a crash in the case that the variable has not been initialized in `viewDidLoad`.

*Update:* (Motivated by @11684's comment!) You could also keep your property, and use
the associated instance variable for creation and release only:

```
_addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
// ...
if (_addressBook != nil)
    CFRelease(_addressBook);
```

In that case it would make sense to define the property as "read-only".

Comment: You can have a property and an instance variable with the same name. Perhaps that works?

Comment: @11684: Using the associated instance variable of the property is actually a good idea (and it need not have the same name). I have updated the answer accordingly, I hope that is OK for you.

Comment: Why would that not be OK for me?

Comment: @11684: I prefer to ask when I use other people's ideas in my answer!

Comment: Well, your asking is a reason why I would think it's OK in itself. Plus, StackOverflow is for gathering knowledge, not reputation points. @MartinR