# Is ABAddressBookRef an acceptable type for a property?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, abaddressbook

Is this syntax acceptable or is it not best practice?

```
@property ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook;
```

Comment: well, if you need an address book to be the property of your class, then what else would be good?

Comment: Was my original thesis but thought it would be better to change the logic of the class. I'll up vote if nobody wildly disagrees :-)

Comment: @RolandFlyBoy: If you use ARC then this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15861222/1187415 or this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16022019/1187415 might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is completely ok and correct. It probably just feels strange because you generally don't need to make lots of properties with CF types. 
If it is not toll-free bridged, you should be sure to use CFRelease in the dealloc method of your class.